# do we need to drop the #temp table after select into

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I know we will have to drop the table manually after using create table, but how about select into #temp ? will it be cleaned up at the end of the the stored proc? thanks

Comment: Which dmbs? (Doesn't look like a general ANSI SQL question...)

Answer (score 4):

Better late than never, I suppose. In case other people have trouble finding [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms174979):

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped
>   automatically when the stored procedure is finished.